# ContentEditable not working on iOS in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with the contenteditable div in Ionic for iOS. I can tap on the div just fine, and it brings up the keyboard, but when you type it doesn't add text... This is only for iOS. Android and PC works perfectly fine.

There were some resources saying you needed to add `-webkit-user-select: auto;` or `-webkit-user-select: text;` and neither worked.

My html is pretty simple:

```
 <div contenteditable="true" #newPostTextarea [attr.placeholder]="placeholderText" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" maxlength="450" rows="2" (input)='charCount($event, false)' class="newPostTextarea"></div>
```

The only interesting thing might be `attr.placeholder` as I needed a placeholder text.

My CSS is:

```
[placeholder]:empty::before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #c1c1c1 !important;
}

[placeholder]:empty:focus::before {
    content: "";
}

[contenteditable], #newPostTextarea, #replyTextarea {
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    user-select: auto;
    //Also tried text instead of auto.
}
```

As i said this above works perfectly for Android and PC. But not iOS for some reason.

You tap on the `div` and the keyboard shows up, the placeholder disappears, but as you type nothing shows up in the `div`. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @raymondboswel no I never found a solution. I just reverted back to `ion-textarea` and developed a way to show bold and italics. Sorry :/

Comment: Hi Simon, I eventually found a solution. If I added the user-select property as a css class it didn't work, but if I applied it directly in the style attribute it did. I have no idea why that would be. E.g

<div
        id="chatInput"
        style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"
        [attr.contenteditable]="!disableInput"       
      ></div>